# Feats that change spell slots into spell points?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, feats, spells

I'm creating a sorcerer for a game and can't find a feat that allows me to change my spell slots into spell points, am I mis-remembering this feat's existance?

Comment: @BESW They're not a default-standard part of Pathfinder, either.

Comment: On a related note, [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19784/how-to-fix-sorcerors-getting-shafted-by-spell-point-variants) brings up and asks about the impact of the spell point variant on sorcerors.

Comment: I cannot more strongly recommend @Ernir's [Psionics-to-Spellcasting translation](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=194002): it is massively superior to the (quite broken) *Unearthed Arcana* spell point system.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no such feat in D&D 3.5. Spell Points are a variant rule (replacing most slot-based magic in the game world), not an option accessible to individual spellcasters via feats or similar customization options.

To increase the flexibility of a Sorcerer via feats, I suggest the *Versatile Spellcaster* feat from Races of the Dragon. It allows you to use lower level slots to power higher level spells - not quite Spell Points, but often close enough.

Answer (score 6):

Usually you just choose to use a spell point variant when you create the character: there’s no feat involved, it’s just something you ask your DM if you can do. I suppose a DM might decide that you can only if you take a feat, but that’s not part of even the variant spell point rules suggested by *Unearthed Arcana*. Actually, the only d20 System game I’m aware of that does have such a feat, here called Manyspell Magus, is [Rule of Cool’s *Legend*](http://www.ruleofcool.com/).